# Using ArcGIS REST Service to query particular features inside BBOX?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, query

I really have 0,0000... knowledge about OGC web services (WMS / WFS ; only limited basics). Therefore maybe this 'stupid' question.

My question might be misplaced / or have the wrong tags... But it's hard to determine what is what without knowledge of it all...

I have a WMS - I use it for retrieving a map image according a specific BBOX.

> https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/ANB/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Since they don't have a matching `WFS` I'm not able to get the features inside the BBOX. Since the `WMS` only deals with a `X/Y` point for getting a feature on that particular point. I have tried with the `BUFFER` parameter but does not seem to work.

I also tried rendering the whole `BBOX` to a 1/1 (width/height) image and getting the features for the single `X/Y` point...  But those results don't always seem correct...

So I gave up on that one, until I found following `ArcGIS REST Service`...
Is there a possibility to obtain the features inside a specific `polygon` or `bbox` using the link below? Opening the link gives me the impression there is a `query` possibility...

> https://www.geoloket.be/gwserver/rest/services/Milieu/AGS_historische_bossen/MapServer/2/query

Comment: The limit on querying at a point is a limit of all WMS (GetFeatureInfo operation).  Some software allows querying for a buffer around a point, but it is not part of the standard.

Comment: How are the two services you list related? If you are saying that you don't want to use WMS and the question is about ArcGIS APIs then you should remove the WMS reference and WMS tag.